# Como ativar Autenticação Basica no Nginx para um caminho do Angular?

Tags: angularjs, angular, nginx

Tenho uma aplicação angular onde quero proteger um caminho específico com autenticação HTTP básica. Os caminhos da aplicação são da forma meusite.com.be/#/example-path.

O arquivo de configuração do Nginx esta assim:

```
location /#/path-to-protect {
    auth_basic           "Area Restrita";
    auth_basic_user_file conf/.htpasswd;
}
```

Mas o caminho não pede autenticação quando acessado.

Testei com outros caminhos sem o # e funcionou normalmente.

Comment: O que você está usando no back-end? Não creio que o "Angular sozinho" vá fazer grande coisa...

Comment: Você rodou o comando?: htpasswd -c /usr/local/nginx/conf/.htpasswd nomedousuário Mais informações em:
https://medium.com/galata/aumentando-a-seguran%C3%A7a-do-seu-site-com-autentica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-http-e-nginx-b6a5b006a52

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você não tem como fazer desta forma. A parte das URLs depois do caractére `#` nunca é passada para o servidor. - Isso está na especificação das URLs em si.

O Angular utiliza esse recurso justamente para fazer operações do lado do cliente - ele executa código dependendo do que vem depois do "#" - mas essa parte da URL nunca é passada para o servidor - e, portanto, nenhuma configuração possível no servidor vai poder fazer nada com uma URL que só
é distinta de outra por coisas que venham depois do "#".

Se você quer travar telas para os usuários de uma web-app "single page", tem que fazer isso com código em Javascript no próprio angular - você pode pedir uma identificação de HTTP quando a pessoa acessa o site pela primeira vez, e, do lado do servidor, prover uma variável de papel (role) do usuário atual que a aplicação do lado do cliente vai levar em conta para todas as operações (dessa forma você não tem que gerenciar autenticação e senhas do lado do cliente, se não desejar) - mas mesmo fazendo isso, você vai precisar travar as URLs de dados - "API"s usadas pela sua aplicação, dependendo desse papel. Por que você sempre tem que ter em mente que é o usuário da página que em total controle do ambiente de execução da aplicação do lado do cliente - é só entrar no console de Javascript e alterar diretamente qualquer variável usada pelo Angular. (Então ele poderia alterar o papel de "anônimo" para "administrador" e destravar tudo).

**Resumindo**:

1. Não dá pra travar telas e "páginas" do ângular configurando a URL no lado do servidor;
2. Você até tem como travar, para fins estéticos, o acesso a algumas telas e funcionalidades só mexendo no código cliente. Mas qualquer usuário que realmente tenha algo a ganhar com isso pode ter acesso a essas telas mudando o variáveis no Angular diretamente
3. Se você separar os recursos de dados realmente importantes em URLs distintas, mesmo que usadas apenas internamente pelo Angular, você pode controlar acesso as mesmas via uma autenticação básica de HTTP - mas acho que não dá pra exigir essa autenticação, que faz o navegador exibir um pop-up, e etc... num request de "ajax" feito pelo Angular: você vai ter que pedir a autenticação uma vez quando o usuário acessar a aplicação a primeira vez, e instruir usuários não autorizados a usar algo como "guest" senha "guest" - e aí configurar o NGINX de acordo: (acesso apenas a parte dos recursos para o usuário "guest", e a tudo para usuários com um login e senha válidos).
4. Por fim, a forma correta e elegante de fazer isso é realmente programar o lado do Backend, usando algum framework e linguagem de programação conceituados, e fazer toda a parte de autenticação e autorização aí. COm o uso de sistemas de template do framework, pode até dividir a aplicação do Angular, e só deixar subir para o cliente as telas que ele tenha acesso, de acordo com o papel dele no sistema.

**(anexo) informação sobre esquemas de URL**

Aqui a especificação de URIs e URLs pela Internet Engineering Task Force:
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986

E na sessão 3.5, "fragments", você vai encontrar:

> Fragment identifiers have a special role in information retrieval
> systems as the primary form of client-side indirect referencing,
> allowing an author to specifically identify aspects of an existing
> resource that are only indirectly provided by the resource owner.  As
> such, the fragment identifier is not used in the scheme-specific
> processing of a URI; instead, the fragment identifier is separated
> from the rest of the URI prior to a dereference, and thus the
> identifying information within the fragment itself is dereferenced
> solely by the user agent, regardless of the URI scheme.

Traduzindo com algumas anotações:

> Identificadores de fragmento tem um papel especial em sistemas de
> recuperação de informações como a forma primaria de referências
> indiretas do lado do cliente, permitindo que a um autor identificar
> especificamente aspectos de um resource existente que são providos
> apenas de forma indireta pelo dono do resource. Assim sendo, o
> identificador de fragmento não é usado no processamento da URI
> especifico para o esquema; em vez disso, o identificador de fragmento
> é *separado* do restante da URI antes de uma  de-referência (busca no
> servidor, no caso de HTTP), e portanto, a a informação identificadora
> dentro do fragmento em si é  de-referenciada somente no user-agent
> (navegador, no caso de páginas Web), qualquer que seja o esquema da
> URI.